# How to view all SharePoint 2013 Workflows in a custom web page using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, csom

I would like to monitor all of workflows in my site collection using CSOM. What is the best approach to achieve it?

Comment: Depends what you mean by “monitor”. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What I mean by 'Monitor' is to view the status of workflows completed or not in a site collection. - @sasfrog